# Prove that a set is not countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*Please note I'm new to all this - so can you explain it simply please. Really appreciate it*

I'm trying to prove that the set of all **finite and countably infinite sequences over {0,1}** is not countable (I think).

I have tried using the Diagonalisation technique but i'm a bit confused. I know that the set of all finite length strings is countably infinite and using the Diagonalisation technique to construct a language we can proof by contradiction that it is not countable.

Any suggestions on how to complete it or where to start (if i'm thinking about it in the wrong way)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First, it suffices to show that the set of all countable sequences is not countable.  That avoids having to deal with sequences where $x_n$ isn't defined for some $n$. Then we can define a very natural map from that set to $[0,1)$ via $$
  f \,:\, \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} \to [0,1) \,:\, (x_n) \mapsto \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_n2^{-n}
$$

If you can show that $f$ is surjective, and already know that $[0,1)$ has the same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, then it follows that $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ also has at least that cardinality.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, but can you take a step back (just a beginner).
I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Is the set of all finite and countably infinite sequences, infinite? 
If so, why would it be countable?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the fact that the set is finite and countable infinite? Or is it just grouped under countable?

Comment: This is a circular argument. You just showed that $|\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}|\ge|\Bbb R|$ and then claim that $|\Bbb R|=|2^{\aleph_0}|$ is known, but $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}=2^{\aleph_0}$ is the definition, and nowhere does countability show up in any case.

Comment: Sorry - I'm not a mathematician. So I don't understand. Is it possible to explain it in simple terms? Thank you

Comment: @Harry I would recommend my answer or drhab's, which give direct proofs of uncountability, over this one.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I used $2^{\aleph_0}$ merely as a convenient name for the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$, but you're right that this is confusing.

Comment: @fgp Really, involving $\Bbb R$ at all is irrelevant. Most arguments for the uncountability of $\Bbb R$ work by first reducing it to $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$, then use "the diagonal argument" on this space, so relating $\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N}$ to $\Bbb R$ in this instance seems to me like a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Depends. If your goal is to establish the cardinalities of various sets as efficiently as possible, then I agree. But since the OP is a beginner, I felt that showing him that the set of all 0-1 sequences maps naturally to $[0,1)$ might help.

Comment: @fgp If your goal is to show that the set he is interested in is not countable, then your answer does not do that, so I don't see how this is an answer to the question. I don't see any comparison to the cardinality of the natural numbers, so this can't possibly prove uncountability of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\le\omega}$ be the set of all countable sequences of $\{0,1\}$, and suppose $f:\Bbb N\to X$. Now define

$$g(n)=\begin{cases}1&\mbox{if }n\in\operatorname{dom}f(n)\wedge f(n)(n)=0\\0&\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$

If $g=f(n)$ for some $n$, then $g(n)=f(n)(n)=0$ implies $g(n)=1$ and $g(n)=1$ implies $g(n)=0$, a contradiction. Thus $g\notin\operatorname{ran} f$ and $f$ is not surjective. If $X$ was countable, there would be a surjection from $\Bbb N$, so it follows that $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: Thank you, but can you explain yours a bit more. What does 'dom' stand for, i'm not familiar with the notation you used. If you can use the diagonalisation technique for this question, can you explain it using that?

Comment: @Harry A countable sequence is a function from the natural numbers (or a subset) to, in this case, $\{0,1\}$. For example, the sequence $\langle 1,0,1\rangle$ is a function such that $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=0$, and $f(3)=1$. $4$ is not in the domain (that's what 'dom' means) of the function. Thus the function $g$ is only equal to $1$ when the sequence $f(n)$ has an $n$-th term and this term is equal to $0$.

Comment: @Harry The reason this is called the "diagonal technique" is because of the $f(n)(n)$ part. That is, we construct a function by drawing all the $0$'s and $1$'s of each function in a big matrix, then drawing a diagonal line on that matrix and make a new function from those terms (but flipped, so we get a contradiction).

Answer (score 0):

Let $F$ be the set of functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\} $.
Then it corresponds with the set of countably infinite sequences over
$\left\{ 0,1\right\} $. Now assume that $F$ is countable. Then it
can be well-ordered like $F=\left\{ f_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\right\} $
where the $f_{n}$ are functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\} $.
Now define function $g:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\left\{ 0,1\right\} $
by $n\mapsto0$ if $f_{n}\left(n\right)=1$ and $n\mapsto1$ if $f_{n}\left(n\right)=0$
. Then $g\in F$ but $g\ne f_{n}$ for each $n$ and a contradiction
is found. We conclude that $F$ is not countable.